# Cache referred to does not exist

Tags: azure

**History**
In my development environment I've battled a reoccurring error with running Windows Azure Emulator. To resolve before I created a new Solution and projects based on the Azure template, along with reinstalling the October 2012 update SDK. Then I had to copy over all the files into the new projects. Before going through all that, since I know it can work, I wanted to see if there was something else I can do.

**Setup**

- Windows 8
- Visual Studio 2012 Update 1
- IIS Express 8
- Windows Azure Tools - October 2012
- Windows Azure Caching 1.8.1.0
- ASP.NET MVC 4.0 project
- Web Role (2 Instances)
- Cache Worker Role (2 Instances)
- Caching Enabled on Cache Work Roles and set to Dedicated Role (Local Role state is: UseDevelopmentStorage=true)
- Session uses Distributed Cache
- Output Cache uses Distributed Cache

**Web.config settings**

```
    <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="AFCacheSessionStateProvider" cookieName="abc_session">
          <providers>
            <add name="AFCacheSessionStateProvider" type="Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider, Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache" cacheName="default" dataCacheClientName="default" applicationName="AFCacheSessionState" />
          </providers>
        </sessionState>

<outputCache defaultProvider="AFCacheOutputCacheProvider">
        <providers>
          <add name="AFCacheOutputCacheProvider" type="Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheOutputCacheProvider, Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache" cacheName="default" dataCacheClientName="default" applicationName="AFCacheOutputCache" />
        </providers>
      </outputCache>
    </caching>

  <dataCacheClients>
    <dataCacheClient name="default">
      <autoDiscover isEnabled="true" identifier="AppNameCacheWorkerRole" />
    </dataCacheClient>
  </dataCacheClients>
```

**Error Details**

```
ErrorCode<ERRCA0009>:SubStatus<ES0001>:Cache referred to does not exist
[DataCacheException: ErrorCode<ERRCA0009>:SubStatus<ES0001>:Cache referred to does not exist. Contact administrator or use the Cache administration tool to create a Cache.]
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache.ThrowException(ErrStatus errStatus, Guid trackingId, Exception responseException, Byte[][] payload, EndpointID destination) +767
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache.ThrowException(ResponseBody respBody, EndpointID destination) +149
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheFactory.EstablishConnection(IEnumerable`1 servers, RequestBody request, Func`3 sendMessageDelegate, DataCacheReadyRetryPolicy retryPolicy) +967
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Initialize>b__1(RequestBody req) +198
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.SocketClientProtocol.SendReceive(IVelocityRequestPacket request, Func`2 delegate, EndpointID& destination) +121
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.SocketClientProtocol.Initialize(IEnumerable`1 servers) +1011
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheFactory.GetCache(String cacheName, CreateNewCacheDelegate cacheCreationDelegate, DataCacheInitializationViaCopyDelegate initializeDelegate) +1103
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheFactory.GetCache(String cacheName) +131
   Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DataCacheFactoryWrapper.CreateDataCacheFromFactory(DataCacheFactory factory, String cacheName) +63
   Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.CacheHelpers.RunCacheCreationHooks(CacheConnectingEventArgs fetchingEventArgs, IDataCacheFactory dataCacheFactory, Object sender, EventHandler`1 fetchingHandler, EventHandler`1 fetchedHandler) +356
   Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheOutputCacheProvider.CreateInternalProvider(IHttpRuntime httpRuntime, OutputCacheInitializationData initData, IDataCacheFactory dataCacheFactory, EventHandler`1 cacheFetching, EventHandler`1 cacheFetched) +399
   Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheOutputCacheProvider.GetInternalProvider() +315
   Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheOutputCacheProvider.Get(String key) +54
   System.Web.Caching.OutputCache.Get(String key) +80
   System.Web.Caching.OutputCacheModule.OnEnter(Object source, EventArgs eventArgs) +341
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +80
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +165
```

Misc Notes:

- The same configuration works fine when it is deployed to Azure, so has something to do with my local environment.
- IIS Express was crashing when I had more than one instance of web roles setup, and I found a suggestion to run the Visual Studio 2010 SP1 to resolve. I had VS2010 on the system because one tools (believe it was SQL) installed it. Installing SP1 resolved the issue with IIS Express crashing, but then this error reappeared.
- If I comment out the OutputCache node listed above the error goes away.
- If I switch the Cache Worker Role from Dedicated Role to Co-located Role the error goes away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spoke with Microsoft tech support and it appears this a known issue. Most of the time it can be resolved by forcing a refresh in the browser. I've had mixed success. The fix for this issue will be part of the next Azure SDK release.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me in production a lot! I upload my package to staging first, and have to always wait until all the instances are running before hitting the staging URL. Sometimes this error still occurs and I restart all my instances for it to fix itself.

Comment: I can confirm this hasn't happened to me for a while now, I think since ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012.2 Update came out which I believe has an updated Azure SDK in it. They probably fixed this bug on their Azure servers end.